# How to remove this line from the text in word MacOS?

Tags: macos, microsoft-word

I see (Attached pic) this line which is not underline but show up and stay there, whether I replace delete or do whatever it doesn't go away. How can I remove this, I tried everything it is not underline and stay there and brown in colour.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the line disappears if you select and cut or delete the whole paragraph of text around it, my guess is that it's probably just a stray drawing object. And if you can't click it directly to select it, it may have its **Wrapping style** property set to **Behind text**.

In this case, when you select the whole paragraph, the object's anchor icon should become visible, as shown here:

[image: Anchor for drawing object]

While the paragraph is still selected, you should now be able to click the drawing object directly and have it become individually selected, as shown by the circles at each end:

[image: Drawing object selected]

At this point, you can just press <kbd>Delete</kbd> (<kbd>Backspace</kbd> in Windows) to delete it.

If the anchor doesn't appear when you select the paragraph (and doesn't disappear when you cut/delete that paragraph), it may be anchored in the page's header or footer. In this case, open the header, and press <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> in Windows) to select all. If the object is anchored there, the anchor icon will appear, and you can delete the object. If the anchor doesn't appear, repeat this step in the footer.

Answer (score 0):

did you check the Draw Borders? Or Check Spelling?

it looks like this [image]

or this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I could remove it and worked as shown by cnread. I cut pasted big chunk of upper and lower paragraph than only I could see it is separate line and then pasted text in the text editor and copy paste again in the word document same place with the paste special option with unformatted text.

Thanks